# changing folder permissions to admin

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I have a bash script to create and move files

This script is making folder bassed on file name and then create another folder downloads
example movie.mkv

movie/downloads/movie.mkv

```
for file in *.mkv; do
  folder=$(basename "$file" ".mkv")"/downloads"
  mkdir -p "$folder" && mv "$file" "$folder"
done
```

but folders created by this script have root permissions and I need admin permissions

Is there any way to edit this script?

Here is a picture what I want to change:
    http://s5.postimg.org/5cmxxf8on/Bez_tytu_u.jpg

Best Regards and THank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're running script as `root` you can add `chown` command as the last command in script to change owner to admin:

```
for file in *.mkv; do
  folder=$(basename "$file" ".mkv")"/downloads"
  mkdir -p "$folder" && mv "$file" "$folder"
  chown -R admin "$folder"
done
```

Comment: Thank You but it's changing only one folder named "downloads" and I need the first one too. Is there any way to change first and second folder

Comment: What is 2nd folder here?

Comment: The one named based on filename of .mkv file movie/downloads/movie.mkv

Comment: You're creating only one folder here `"$folder"` and that is where you're copying files so that is the one needs to change ownership. `chown -R` is recursive command that will change ownership on every file/folder inside `"$folder"`

Comment: OK so maybe You can create another simple script which will be changing all permissions to admin in /root/Desktop/MOVIES thank you for your kindness :)

Comment: You can run chown outside for loop also as: `chown -R admin /root/Desktop/MOVIES`

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.